# Find the marginal pdf of a joint distribution

Tags: probability, self-learning

Let $X$ and $Y$ have a uniform distribution on the set of points with integer coordinates in $S = \{(x,y):0\leqq x\leqq7, x \leqq y \leqq x+2\}$. That is, $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{24}\in S$, and both x and y are integers.

Find $f_X(x)$

I can compute in my head that $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{8}$ (which is the correct answer). However I would like to solve this using the definition: $$f_X(x)=\sum_y f(x,y) = P(X=x), x \in S$$

I am not quite sure how to write the summation in this format given that for each $x$ there are three possible values for $y$.

Comment: It will be easier if you plot the graph before calculation.

Comment: You have proved it. For any $x$ there are $3$ possible values of $y$, so $\sum_{x\le y\le x+2}f(x,y)=\sum_{x\le y\le x+2}\frac{1}{24}=\frac{3}{24}$.